# jQuery issue on dynamic JavaScript loading at Cloud9

Tags: javascript, jquery, socket.io, cloud9-ide

I got an issue of dynamically loading JavaScript on a project (https://c9.io/etlolap/webapp) at Cloud9 IDE.

The server file of (https://c9.io/etlolap/webapp/socket.js) monitors the project's file system, detects changed files, and sends changed files to client over socket.io. It works fine so I would skip directly putting its content here.

The data file (https://c9.io/etlolap/webapp/public/js/data.js) contains only one line.

```
var b = "Hello World!";
```

Later, we change it to:

```
var b = "Goodbye!";
```

The client file of (https://c9.io/etlolap/webapp/socket.html) displays the value of variable b from data.js. In case of a file change (to `"Goodbye!"`), the new version of data.js is supposed to reload and new value of b gets displayed automatically.

```
<!doctype html>
<!--socket.html- dynamic JS loading example -->
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://webapp-c9-etlolap.c9.io/public/js/jq/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://webapp-c9-etlolap.c9.io/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script id="script_a" src="https://webapp-c9-etlolap.c9.io/public/js/data.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function(){
        $( 'body' ).html( b );
      });
      io.connect("https://webapp-c9-etlolap.c9.io")
        .on('script', function( path ){
          $( '#script_a' ).remove();
          $( 'head' ).append(
            '<script id="script_a" src="https://webapp-c9-etlolap.c9.io'  
            + path + 
            '"></scr' + 'ipt>'
          );
          $( 'body' ).html( b ); //<---culprit!
        });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Loading...
  </body>
</html>
```

Everything works fine including socket.io. The only issue is that the new value of b couldn't get refreshed. Debugger showed that, at the `$( 'body' ).html( b );` inside iolconnect().on(), the new value of b didn't get refreshed and it's still `"Hello World!"`.

Dose anyone know why? How can I get the new version of data.js refresh into the socket.html?

Comment: And that is why I try to avoid cloud IDEs

Answer (score 0):

I see you are appending the script and not waiting for it to load before you update the body.

I just tried in your workspace:

```
setTimeout(function() {
   $( 'body' ).html( b );
}, 1000);
```

And it worked as expected. So, it's not a Cloud9 script loading issue.

You can also try doing the update inside the loaded script file.

Mostafa,
Cloud9 IDE Developer